# a part of the icing on my donut looks strange

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have been following Blender guru's donut tutorial But after sculpting, in Cycles render view mode, the left part of the icing looks quite strange and has orange colour. The problem only appeared after sculpting but if I change subsurface value into 0, the orange part on the icing is gone and my donut look fine. I have attached the image of my donut

[image: donut] .
Could anyone point out what is wrong in my settings?

Comment: It's probably some of your "icing" mesh clipping into the "donut" mesh. Try moving the affected areas of the icing "up" slightly. (Hint: use proportional edit (O) select a vertex at the center of the problem area and move it on the Z axis)

Comment: I lifted a vertex of the icing a bit. nothing has changed. Even after separating the icing from the donut, the orange part was still on the icing. It looks to me that the base colour on the affected area is gone. but I have no idea why.